# What does "Thundering typhoons" mean?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

What does "Thundering typhoons" mean?
Actually it was in the 2011 movie The Adventures of Tintin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Thundering typhoons!* is an alliterative phrase (sometimes in the extended form *Ten thousand thundering typhoons!*) used by Leslie Lonsdale-Cooper and Michael Turner to translate Hergé's *Tonnerre de Brest!* (a loud daily canon shot to announce the closure of the arsenal at Brest).

It is simply a exclamation not designed to mean anything.  [Captain Haddock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Haddock#Expletives) also says *Blistering barnacles* (or *Billions of bilious blue blistering barnacles!*) as a translation of *Mille millions de mille milliards de mille sabords!* (literally, thousands of millions of thousands of billions of thousands of portholes).