# What does “you blue blistering barnacles” or "Billions of blue blistering barnacles" mean?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “Thundering typhoons” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60801/what-does-thundering-typhoons-mean)

What does "you blue blistering barnacles" or "Billions of blue blistering barnacles" mean?

Comment: Give more context.

Comment: This should possibly be merged with the Thundering Typhoons question: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/60801/3820

Comment: Mike - you have your answer in your previous Tintin question.

Comment: This should be closed – not just because it's a duplicate, but because it has the potential to stick the Sponge-Bob Squarepants theme song in everyone's head.

Comment: got it , sorry for duplicate !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Blistering barnacles* is a "euphemistic oath" used by [Captain Haddock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Haddock),  a fictional character in [The Adventures of Tintin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Tintin), who sometimes extends the alliteration to *"Billions of bilious blue blistering barnacles!"*, for example.

It doesn't really "mean" anything, being just a made-up exclamation coined by the author ([Herge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herg%C3%A9)) so as not to offend anyone. But it'll have become much better known (effectively, a [catchphrase](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/catch+phrase)) since [Spielberg's animated film version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Tintin_%28film%29) was released last year.

Comment: Isn't Tintin written in French?  Does Captain Haddock swear in English anyway?  Or is this alliterative exclamation due to a translator?

Comment: @GEdgar: Yes, Herge wrote the originals in French. He probably had a tolerable command of English, but I don't know how involved he'd have been in the translations for worldwide syndication. I'm pretty sure there was no "direct" equivalent "curse" in the French, where he said things like *"mille sabords!" (thousands of portholes)*. Curiously though, I think he was actually called Captaine **Haddock** in the original!

Comment: According to [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/60806/3559) the translators coined them, but that is a minor detail.

Comment: @Matt Эллен: Oh dear! I hadn't seem that earlier one, or I wouldn't have bothered answering this one. I can't imagine why OP would wait a couple of weeks and then ask what's effectively the same question again, in order to be given the same answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it puzzles me too :)

Answer (score 6):

More specifically, barnacles are a kind of crustacean that lives on the bottom of ships and boats, and are usually considered vermin that get in the way of steering the boat. Captain Haddock, being a seaman, uses this as an expletive.